# based on array object key value need to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React error fields which i will be displaying on the screen.

```
this.state = {
    errorMerchantid: '',
    errorPassword: '',
    errorRePassword: '' 
}
```

error fields will be dynamic. it may have like below

```
err.response.data={
    merchantID: 'merchant id error'
}
```

in the above case i have one field error which is merchantID, then I need to setState like below.

```
this.setState ({errorMerchantid: err.response.data.merchantID })
```

or

```
err.response.data={
    merchantID: 'merchant id error',
    password: 'invalid password'
}
```

in the above case i have 2 fields error which is merchantID and password, then I need to setState like below

```
 this.setState ({errorMerchantid: err.response.data.merchantID, 
                 errorPassword: err.response.data.errorPassword})
```

or

```
err.response.data={
    merchantID: 'merchant id error',
    password: 'invalid password',
    repassword: 'invalid re-entered password'
}
```

in the above case i have 3 fields error which is merchantID, password and repassword, then I need to setState like below.

```
 this.setState ({errorMerchantid: err.response.data.merchantID, 
                  errorPassword: err.response.data.errorPassword, 
                  repassword: err.response.data.repassword  })
```

Comment: what code you have written till now?can you show it ?

Comment: const errorResponseFields = Object.keys(err.response.data)
                const formFields = ['merchantID', 'password', 'repassword']

                const errorFeilds = errorResponseFields.every((fields) => {
                     //formFields.includes(fields)
                     confused here how to achieve  
                })

Comment: you could just use the same name for error state and just do "this.setState(err.response.data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with the updates to the state, and populate it conditionally

```js
// err.response.data
const {merchantID,password,repassword} = err.response.data;
const errors = {};

if (merchantID){
  errors.errorMerchantid = merchantID;
}
if (password){
  errors.errorPassword = password;
}
if (merchantID){
  errors.errorRePassword = repassword;
}

this.setState(errors);
```

---

If you need to reset the other errors each time then you could do

```js
// err.response.data
const {merchantID,password,repassword} = err.response.data;
const errors = {
  errorMerchandId: merchantID || '',
  errorPassword: password || '',
  errorRePassword: repassword || ''
};


this.setState(errors);
```

Keep in mind that you need to be consistent with the case of the state properties are they are case-sensitive.